# Java Validations GUI Netbeans

Tags: java, validation, user-interface, netbeans

Hello i have a GUI Netbeans project for java when i click submit it checks validations for textfields

Here is my code

```
private void btnSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          


    //VALIDATIONS-----------------------------------------------------------
    if(txtName.getText().trim().equals(""))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Must have name");
        jlblNameVer.setVisible(true);

    }
    else 
    {
        jlblNameVer.setVisible(false);
    }

    //ID VERIFICATION
    if (txtIdNumber.getText().trim().equals(""))
   {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Photo Id must not be emplty");
   }

    //EMAIL VALIDATION
    if(txtEmail==null ||txtEmail.getText().length() < 10|| txtEmail.getText()== null ||!(txtEmail.getText().trim().contains("@") && txtEmail.getText().trim().contains(".")))
    {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Email");
     }

    //Phone Number Validation
     if(txtPhoneNum.getText().length() < 10)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Must atleast 10 characters");
    }

     //COMBOBOX VALIDATIONS
     if(cmbStayDuration.getSelectedIndex() == -1)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select stay duration");
    }

     //Photo ID
      if(cmbPhotoId.getSelectedIndex() == -1)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select Photo ID type");
    }

    String roomType = cmbRoomType.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String roomNumber = cmbRoomNumber.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String checkin = ftxtCheckinDate.getText();
    String checkout = txtCheckOut.getText();
    String Name = txtName.getText();
    String IdType = cmbPhotoId.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
    String IdNumber = txtIdNumber.getText();
    String Phone = txtPhoneNum.getText();
    String email = txtEmail.getText().trim();


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,roomType,roomNumber,checkin,checkout,Name,IdType,IdNumber,Phone,email);

NOT WORKING (optionpane with variables)^^^^^^^^


}
```

I wont to make sure that if all of those are correct  then the program has a popup window which displays all the variables entered into the form.

here is a picture of GUI
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygp1G.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) does not accept so many parameters. You should concatenate strings and not pass them separately.

Try :

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Title", roomType+roomNumber+checkin+checkout+Name+IdType+IdNumber+Phone+email, JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an Array to the option pane. Each Object in the Array will be displayed on a different line:

```
String[] messages = new String[3];
messages[0] = "Message line1";
messages[1] = "Message line1";
messages[2] = "Message line1";

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
    null, // parent frame
    messages,
    "Multiline Message",
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more examples and features of the JOptionPane.